# Why does tailing an output log sometimes give partial lines?

Tags: pipe, tail

Sometimes, tailing an output log which is constantly being updated doesn't give the whole lines. Why is that?

```
grep pattern input_file > output.log &
tail output.log
```

Why doesn't it print the last line in full?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading and writing a file is not line-atomic, and `tail -f` is not line-buffered. So, when `tail -f` reads the file while it was still being written, it may reach the end of the file (and therefore stop printing) before the process writing to the file writes the end of the line. When that happens, it prints an incomplete line because that's all it sees.

Comment: If you any source links, can you please post those links? I would like to do further reading on that. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @tech_learner Look into [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). The article is more focused on single variables, but the same principles apply to whole files (even more so, perhaps).